# Can I create a separate /home partition with a guided option during installation?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, lvm

I am familiar with the benefits of having a separate `/home` partition when performing system reinstalls; the `/` directory is wiped out with the new system files, but user data is preserved in `/home`. I am performing a clean Kubuntu install, and would like to make sure I can do this. I am not familiar with LVM options; in other Linux distributions, I have used separate partitions.

The install options are:

- Guided - use entire disk
- Guided - use entire disk and set up LVM
- Guided - use entire disk and set up encrypted LVM
- Manual

Does one of these guided options allow me to separate the `/home` partition so reinstallations in the future go smoothly? Do I need to make changes once installation is completed to achieve this? Or is it simpler to just use the manual option?

The "guided" descriptor seems poor. Selecting any of these options is a final decision; there are no further options for modifying the disk configuration after making a guided selection.

Comment: I believe only the Something Else/manual install option allows you to create partitions during install. All the auto install options create / (root) & swap. Then you have to create & rearrange partitions after install.https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing and: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace and if not booting Windows, you can use gpt whether UEFI or BIOS: http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - the guided options will not let you create (or recover) a separate `/home`. Both of these tasks have to be done through the "`Manual`" method (so you can choose to mount, but not format `/home` next time). 
YMMV and assuming a modern disk, Set up at least 3 partitions (use an extended partition):

`swap` I recommend 3x `RAM`
`/`    I use 32G 44% full (if I have it)
`/home` the remainder.